# Parse Error in GTM Custom Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement a JavaScript custom variable in GTM, which should check the url, and depending if a specific string is contained in it returns either a value or another.

```
function(){
    var url = {Page URL}
  if(url.includes('a-string')){
        return url.split("/")[6] } else {
        return  'test';
    }
    return;
};
```

I get this error: `Error at line 3, character 18: Parse error. '}' expected`

Can anybody help?

Comment: `{Page URL}` not valid JS syntax

Comment: also, that last `return;` is redundant, since you return in both if and else conditions - but the error is pointing to the U of  {Page ***URL***}

Comment: Hi Jaromanda , {Page URL} is not standard JS syntax, but it is specific to Google Tag Manager (GTM). So that should not be the issue.

Comment: yet, that seems to be where the error is pointing (try adding spaces, before that line, see if the `Error at line 3, character 18` shifts with it

Comment: yes it's that line. Thanks I was confused by the fact that it says line 3. I'm still not sure what is the issue though, because {Page URL}.split("/")[6] } without if/else condition does return the right value.

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX I found the issue. In GTM special variables have to be defined with double curly brackets, in this case {{Page URL}}. Thanks for your help. If you want to submit this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: nah, I had no idea what the problem was, only guessed **where** it was :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the built in variable "Page URL" from the Google Tag Manager you need to put it in double brackets within the code.

```
function(){
    var url = {{Page URL}}
  if(url.includes('a-string')){
        return url.split("/")[6] } else {
        return  'test';
    }
    return;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

try with indexOf() to check if url contain any string u are interested

```
function(){
    var url = {Page URL}
    if(url.indexOf('a-string')){
          return url.split("/")[6] } else {
          return  'test';
      }
    return;
};
```

Comment: how will that be different? indexOf is `-1` when includes is false, so even the logic is now changed by using it